# How to translate "Politicae oeconomiae inscientia"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I came across this phrase whilst reading *[Crotchet Castle](http://www.thomaslovepeacock.net/Crotchet.html)*, by Thomas Love Peacock. It says:

> The moment you admit that [...], [then] the whole of that curious fabric of postulates and dogmas, which you call the science of political economy, and which I call *politicæ oeconomiæ inscientia*, tumbles to pieces.

The translation of the first two words is I think simple: *political economy*. But I am struggling with [inscientia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inscientia). I think it's being used as an adjective, probably as *ignorant*. But the phrase sound slightly odd to me:

> ... and which I call *the ignorant political economy*, tumbles to pieces.

I mean, a science (or pseudo-science, or scientific discipline) is not ignorant. An individual can be. Am I understanding this correctly?

PS: I'm also quite shocked that economics is *oeconomia* rather than *economia*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### "The un-science of political economy"

*Scientia* fundamentally means knowledge, as in Bacon's famous motto, *nam ipsa scientia potestās est* "for knowledge itself is power". But it's also the origin of the modern word "science", and I think that's the sense that's intended here.

So while *īnscientia* literally means "ignorance" or "inexperience", I think it's meant here to contrast with "the science of political economy". I would calque it as "un-science".

For a more natural English translation, which doesn't preserve the pun, you could say **the ignorance of political economy**.

P.S. *Oeconomia* is a loan from Greek, *οἶκος* "home" + *νόμος* "law". The sequences *oe* and *ae* in Latin and Greek-via-Latin words tend to become plain *e* in English.